# CURSOR in proc that only locks current row being UPDATEd (while UPDATing) and nothing else for duration?

Tags: php, mysql, cursor, innodb, deadlock

Please bear with me because I'm hopeless on vocabulary, and my own searches aren't going anywhere.

I've learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14222414/1382306) that if I update in the way I want to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14106032/1382306) (with the `GROUP_CONCAT`s also stored in user-defined vars), I'll lock the entire table.

I'm fairly certain the best way to do this would be to `UPDATE` row by row in a `CURSOR`, starting with the highest PK id then descending because I'm sure I will have a lower chance of a deadlock, or conflict, or whatever it's called (told you I was bad with the vocab) if I start from the most recent record.

The column being `UPDATE`d has no index.

I just found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4735485/1382306) that a `TRIGGER` is a `TRANSACTION` by default, so I will make a proc instead and call from php.

The transaction isolation level is `REPEATABLE-READ`.

I'm more concerned with these overlapping `UPDATE`s causing deadlocks with nothing happening than them taking time to complete.

All tables InnoDB.

All `SELECT`s and `UPDATE`s are `WHERE`d on PK id except for the `CURSOR` `SELECT` which `SELECT`s all ids in the table that's being `UPDATE`d.  No joins.  No muss.  No fuss.

That said, here finally are the questions:

1. Will the `DECLARE`'s `SELECT` only `SELECT` once, or does that also loop (I'd prefer it to `SELECT` only once)?
2. Will the `DECLARE`'s `SELECT`'s lock remain for the duration of the proc (I'd prefer it to release asap)?
3. Will the row lock for each `UPDATE` release as soon as the query is finished, or will they remain for the duration of the proc (I'd prefer the row lock release after the individual `UPDATE` query has finshed)?
4. Will the `SELECT`s for the user variables also release after they've been set (you guessed it: I prefer those also to release asap)?
5. Will it be possible to still `SELECT` the row being `UPDATE`d with the row lock (again, I'd prefer if I could)?

Many thanks in advance!

**Why `UPDATE` all on `INSERT`**

In my website (in my profile), I allow users to access all submitted links ever.  That's fine on a sequential basis, I simply reference the id.

However, I also rank them on a combined percentile of a custom algorithm on the the 3 vote types, equally weighting the 3.

The problem is that in my algorithm, each vote affects all other votes.  There's no way around this because of the nature of my algorithm.

**On Demand**

I tried that route with PHP.  No go.  There's too much calculating.  I'm not so concerned with users having accurate data *instantly* because the page will automatically update the ranks for the user with the user being non the wiser, but I can't have the user waiting forever because I allow rapid dynamic pagination.

Calculating in a view was an even greater disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `DECLARE`'s `SELECT` will **select** only once, but I am afraid, that won't help you ...
- The `SELECT` cursor might keep **something** locked from `OPEN` up to `CLOSE` - what it is depends on your storage engine: It can be table, page, row or nothing
- The `UPDATE` will lock for as long as the update takes. Again, depending on your storage engine, the lock can be table, page or row (but obviously not nothing)

But you might consider a completely different approach: IIUC, you basically want some ranking or percentile match and you try to do this by reacting to every `INSERT`. This has a big problem in my POV: You calculate lots and lots of unneeded values. What would happen, if you calculate only on a reading operation?

- If there is **allways exactly one** `INSERT` between two reading operations, you have to recalculate allways - same case as if you calculate allways as now.
- If there are **no** `INSERT`s between two reading operations, the MySQL query cache will have kept the result of the prior calculation and will not rerun the query, so you calculate less.
- If there are **more than one** `INSERT`s between two reading operations, you need to calculate only once for N inserts.

So, calculating the rank/percentile **on demand** will never be more expensive than calculating on `INSERT`, but it has the potential to be significantly cheaper.